# How to use correctly TestNG annotations with Cucumber framework

Tags: java, selenium, maven, cucumber, testng

I am building TestNG and Cucumber framework, and want to use TestNG annotations like `@BeforeMethod, @AfterMethod` which will run `setUp` and `tearDown` methods before and after each scenario. It works fine if I keep all my Cucumber scenarios in separate feature files. But if I have multiple scenarios in the same feature file `@AfterMethod` is not running after each scenario.

Also have issues if using cucumber Before and After, they work fine only if I put them in StepDefinition file below:

```
public class StepDefinition extends Base {
    
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        openBrowser();
        maximizeWindow();
//      implicitWait(30);
        deleteAllCookies();
//      setEnv();
    }
    
    @After
    public void quit() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Given("^Navigate to ACT landing page$")
    public void navigate_to_ACT_landing_page() throws Throwable {
        LandingPage landingPage = new LandingPage();
        landingPage.navigateToLandingPage();
    }

    @Then("^Verify landing page is rendered$")
    public void verify_landing_page_is_rendered() throws Throwable {
        LandingPage landingPage = new LandingPage();
        landingPage.landingPageRendered();
    }

}
```

But if I put them in separate class (like below) they don't work (in documentation says that they can be put anywhere in the project)

```
package com.act.hooks;


import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.moodys.act.base.Base;

public class Hooks extends Base {
    
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        openBrowser();
        maximizeWindow();
//      implicitWait(30);
        deleteAllCookies();
//      setEnv();
    }
    
    @After
    public void quit() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Comment: Cucumber does not recommend to prepare and clean states using TestNG annotations. If you only start building your framework and want it to be stable, reliable and understandable you would better adhere the recommendations provided buy teams who support technologies which you put to the base of your framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cucumber does not recommend to prepare and clean states using TestNG annotations.
In order to take maximum benefits of TestNG, you can try using pure TestNG implementation for [BDD with QAF](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#bdd). It considers each scenario as [TestNGMethod](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/javadoc/com/qmetry/qaf/automation/step/client/TestNGScenario.html).

If you want to use cucumber then you can add [qaf-cucumber](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber#qaf-cucumber) dependency and use [TestNG factory](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber#using-qaf-cucumber-with-qaf-bdd-runner). It will allow to use TestNG listeners and lifecycle methods (@BeforeMethod, @AfterMethod). When using cucumber with qaf you can choose either to utilize [TestNG life-cycle](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber#using-qaf-cucumber-with-qaf-bdd-runner) or [cucumber life-cycle](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber#using-qaf-cucumber-with-cucumber-runner).

Furthermore, if you are working with webdriver or appium it has inbuilt thread-safe driver management so you don't need to worry about driver management.

Answer (score 1):

There are cucumber provided tags/hooks @Before and @After which runs just before and after each scenario where you can have your setup and teardown code included. Is there any specific reason you want to use testng annotations for doing so ?

This link may help for cucumber @Before and @ After tags.

https://www.google.com/amp/www.automationtestinghub.com/cucumber-hooks-before-after/amp/

Comment: Tried those cucumber Before and After, and got another issue, they work fine only if I put them in StepDefinition file, if I put them in separate class they don't work (in documentation says that they can be put anywhere in the project)

Comment: What do you mean under *Step Definition file*? You can spread your steps definitions across multiple classes. Probably better share your code so that we could look at your issue closer..

Comment: In the glue section of your @cucumberOption, you can either add package name of where your hook file resides or you can provide a path of a hook files. In your case include com.act.hooks in glue. Hope this helps.